# Getting general data throughput in socket streams

Tags: java

I'm just looking for a rough estimate of data in and out of my socket server. I figured using serialize would be the trick since I can count the bytes of an object. I know there's `Instrumentation` but don't want to use that. Why is int coming back at 81?!?! Its supposed to be 4 bytes.

I'm no expert on the guts of serialize beside some basics, but I didn't expect 81!

```
int x = 1;
long test1 = Tools.serialize("1").length; // returns 8
long test2 = Tools.serialize(x).length; // returns 81 ???

private static byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
    o.writeObject(obj);
    return b.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `serialize(x)`, x will be boxed to an `Integer` object then `writeObject` will serialize the entire `Integer` object and not the just the value its `int` value.

You have to do special treatment for ever type

```
o.writeInt(x);
o.writeLong(x); etc...
```

this could be as simple as that

```
if(obj.getClass().equals(Integer.class)){
    Integer i = (Integer) obj;
    o.writeInt(i.intValue());
}
else if(obj.getClass().equals(Long.class)){
   Long l = (Long) obj;
   o.writeLong(l.longValue());
}....
else {
   o.writeObject(obj);
}
```

There are loads of libraries that do serialisation stuff with backward and forward compatibilities, pick one

Comment: Yes, and the solution is to have multiple override methods, `serialize(int val)`, `serialize(long val)` etc

Comment: If I have a custom Object that has Strings and primitives within it, will it calc the int as 4? Actually going to test this real quickly.

Comment: @kenyu73 no, your custom object will be serialised using java serialisation which is verbose

Answer (score 1):

Because you are passing it as an object not as a primitive data type, you should actually use `o.writeInt(val)`

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
    o.writeInt(1);
    System.out.println(b.toByteArray().length); //4
```

So what you should do is to write multiple methods for it like

```
serialize(int num){...}
serialize(Object obj){...}
```

also this might be interesting http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072752/the-java-serialization-algorithm-revealed.html